# Using Ext.ProgressIndicator during ajax calls in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, progress-bar

Ext.ProgressIndicator doesn't have any examples / sample code,

does anyone know how to use this while ajax calls and waiting for response?

methods like

```
setDynamic()   

sourcesetFallbackText()

setLoadingText()
```

don't have any effect on the progress display text. Or am I using them incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create the progress indicator, which is quick and easy:

```
var progressIndicator = Ext.create("Ext.ProgressIndicator", {
    loadingText: "Uploading: {percent}%"
});
```

Then in your XHR request, you'll set the progress property like so:

```
...
progress: progressIndicator
...
```

I would have put an example together for you myself, but I found one on GitHub here: https://github.com/senchalabs/ajax_demos/blob/master/ajax-upload.html

You may also want to check out this existing bug as it deals with file upload and effects versions <= 2.3.1: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?275277-File-Upload-from-Sencha-Touch-2.3-app

Happy Coding!